# Acces Array of object and accesing or checking ut

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, formatting

> So i tried to make the program that formattting the input to be array and object, but i struggle to acces, check, and add an object to an array, here's the code, input and output
>
> 1. The program will ask for input from the user, the request will be formatted as:
>    {
>    name : (inputName),
>    location : (inputlocation),
>    request : [
>    {(productName ) : (totalRequest)}
>    e.g : {meatball : 1},
>    ],
>    }
> 2. The program will check whether the same item has been previously ordered by the same user
> 3. If it is, then the totalRequest of the same item will be increased, if not, an object will be created with the format {productName : totalRequest }

```
let user = {
        name : readLine.question("Name : "),
        location : readLine.question('Location : '),
        request : []
}

while(true){
    var product = readLine.question('input your request : ').toLowerCase();
    var total = readLine.question("total request : ");
    var requestProduct = {}
    //this is the part of the problem, the data is checked in here 
    for(let i of user.request){
        for(let j in i){
            if(j == product){
                i[product] += total;
            } else {
                requestProduct[product] = total;
                user.request.push(requestProduct);
            }
        }
    }
    var isEnough = readLine.question('Enough ?(yes/no)');
    if(isEnough == 'yes'){
        console.log(user);
        break;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

/** 
 * expected output :
 * {
 * name : Budi,
 * Location : Supeno Street, number 150,
 * request : [
 *          {meatball : 12},
 *          {"ice tea" : 12},
 *      ]
 * }
 * output on reality: 
 * {
 * name : Budi,
 * Location : Supeno Street, number 150,
 * request : []
 * }
 * */
```

> i've commented the problem part on the code review, i hope someone can help me solve the problem

Comment: This is horrible data structuring. It should either be a single object like `{meatball: 12, "ice tea": 10}` or an array of objects with the same properties: `[{item: "meatball", quantity: 12}, {item: "ice tea", quantity: 10}]`. Objects with dynamic property names in an array are very hard to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't loop through the object. Use `Object.keys()` to get the key of the object. Then you can check if this key matches what the user entered.

```js
let found = false;
for (let i of user.request) {
  let key = Object.keys(i)[0];
  if (key == product) {
    found = true;
    i[key] += total;
    break;
  }
}

if (!found) {
  user.request.push({[product]: total});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also thanks for the data formatting tips, i'll try to apply those and learn more, have a great day!